# How to set content type for part in XQ message

Tags: java, jms

We can get content type by calling method: `XQPart.getContentType()` but I don't know how to set content type for the current part of XQ message

`setContent(this.getContent(), "my_content_type")` doesn't work

[XQPart interface docs](http://documentation.progress.com/output/Sonic/8.0.0/Docs8.0/api/esb_api/com/sonicsw/xq/XQPart.html#getContentType%28%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setContent(this.getContentType(), "some_stuff") doesn't work

This should be `setContent("<your stuff>", "<content-type>");`, i.e. the first argument is the actual content and the second argument is its type.

E.g.

```
setContent("this is sample text", "text/plain");
setContent("<html><body>this is sample html</body></html>", "text/html");
setContent(<XQPart whose content is an excel sheet>, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: thanks, my bad, I meant this.getContent() (question is fixed now). So I have a content already, but I need to change content-type for it.

Comment: then you would simply say `setContent(this.getContent(), "<content-type>");` where content-type is one of the mime-types that best describes the content, like text/html, application/pdf etc.,